# Decoding prediction outputs generated by a pretrained model to human readable labels

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection, pre-trained-model

I'm trying to use a pre-trained object detection model from the [Tensorflow model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md). Basically, I've chosen `faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_oidv4` trained on the Open Images dataset.

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# restore the deep model
sess=tf.Session()
#First let's load meta graph and restore weights
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('pretrained/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_oid_v4_2018_12_12/model.ckpt.meta')
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('pretrained/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_oid_v4_2018_12_12/'))

# Now, let's access and create placeholders variables and
# create feed-dict to feed new data
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
X = graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
feed_dict ={X: image_raw_feature}

#Now, access the op that we want to run. 
num_detections = graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
detection_scores = graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
detection_boxes = graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
 
x1, x2, x3 = sess.run(
    [num_detections, detection_scores, detection_boxes],
    feed_dict
)
```

The outputs `x1, x2, x3` have the shapes `4`, `[4, 100]` and `[4, 100, 4]`.
The problem is that I don't know how to decode the result to human readable labels.
I guess the total number of object categories is 100 as indicated in `x2`? But it seems to be very small compared with what is described in the dataset [Open Images](https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/index.html).

How can I decode the outputs to the labels?

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/82b928fe199588c62be20d4c39e69c3b5b7f649d/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py#L1138), the output tensors should have following shapes:

```
detection_boxes: [batch, max_detection, 4]
detection_scores: [batch, max_detections]
detection_classes: [batch, max_detections]
num_detections: [batch]
```

Here `bacth = 4`, `max_detections = 100` and **it contains all detections with different confidence scores, so you might need to decide on a score threshold to filter out detections with low confidence scores.** Also the `detection_boxes` contain the box encodings in the order of `ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax` and in normalized coordinates, you need to get the shape of the image to get absolute coordinates.

For example, say you want all detections with `score > 0.5`:

```
final_boxes = []
for i in range(int(num_detections)):
    final_boxes.append(detection_boxes[i, detection_scores[i]>0.5, ])
```

This will give you detections with confidence score higher than 0.5.

Comment: Indeed I'm using 4 images as the input. 
What's the meaning of `max_detections`? Why it's equal to 100.
Normally, I think it should be the number of classes (categories). For example, the number of classes in ImageNet is 1000, so the `detection_scores` should be `[batch_size, 1000]`, isn't it?
Because the model is trained using the Open Images dataset, containing around `600` object categories, I don't know why I got `100` here.

Comment: `max_detections` is the **maximum number of objects that can be detected on a single image**, if your image has more than 100 objects to be detected, then only 100 of them will be detected.  `max_detections` has nothing to do with the number of categories. The number of classes is 1000, the `detection_score` is still of shape [batch_size, max_detections] (e.g. [4,100]). 1000 means the classes value ranges from 1 to 1000, for example, `detection_classes` could be [1,2,52,6,732,7,7,...,3,287,832,322,231]  but the length of `detection_classes` is 100.

Comment: It makes sense to me.
And how do I map from the class index (e.g. 1,2,52) to the corresponding label?
Is there a function in Tensorflow for mapping the labels or I'll have to make one?
For example, in Keras, there is a function named `decode_predictions` for each pretrained model, so I just need to call this function to convert the output probabilities to labels.

Comment: I'm asking because for one dataset (e.g. Open Images), there are different versions and the number of classes changes across versions.
Therefore, if the mapping function is not available, it is not easy to obtain the correct labels (they didn't mention which version of the dataset used for training).

Comment: There is a `label.pbtxt` file that maps class numbers to class names. So during training, the class name will be mapped to the class number and during inference, class number is mapped back to the class names. Usually this mapping is specific to the data (or versions). So if you are using a pretrained network, you will have to find and use the specific corresponding `label.pbtxt` file.  https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/data here is a link to some sample `label.pbtxt` files.

Comment: I found some functions already implemented to convert between categories and indices in here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py